# Screen get black

Tags: syslinux

I have a laptop HP EliteBook 840
I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
When I work, the screen suddenly turn into black "it is still working". Sometimes it stays like this for 4 t0 6 seconds. And some times I should press a key in the keyboard to get it back. 
And sometimes it stays like this and I should turn off the whole laptop by power button to re- turn it on
It does not happen when I work on Windows, it just happen when I work on any kind of Linux.
Any idea about how to fix this issue??
Thanks

Comment: When you say "any kind of Linux", which ones have you seen the problem with (other than 18.04)?

Comment: with linux mint too. the last version